# How to archive logical volume in Linux?

Tags: linux, archive, volume

Because of project requirement, We need to archive logical volume in CentOS 6.5.

We do not care the file and file system in the logical volume, and just want archive the volume into another place using multi-file. we expect that the archive can be restore into volume and the restored volume has the correct data (file and file system).

Is there some ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your volume up and running while archiving, create a LVM snapshot first. Then, you can use `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 of=...etc
```

To split the file, you can use `split` or `7z`.